# In Symfony2, how do I generate random link for email verification and password modification?

Tags: symfony

As have been said in the title, I want to generate a random link based on the current user for email verification and password modification. I think it has 2 demands:

1. it is randomly generated
2. the controller in symfony can tell the user that this link corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

The controller still needs to know something about that user thats not encrypted, something like the UID.

Along with this, one way of doing a password reset is to send a one-way hash of some other information about the user. So for example, have a function which does something like:

```
function generateLink($user)
{
     $hash = md5($user->email);
     $url = '/reset-password/$uid/$hash';
     return $url;
}
```

Use whatever hashing function you want, MD5 is probably not recommended. 
Then, at the other end, do something like:

```
function checkResetLink($uid, $hash)
{
    $user = get_user($uid); // However you retrieve your user info

    if($hash == md5($user->email)){
         // Log in the user or do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

If you really want it to be randomly generated, you could generate some random hash, and store that in the user record, then when you check it, retrieve that random hash using the uid, and check that it is the same.